# CMake FIND_PACKAGE finds wrong version of SQLite3 on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, sqlite, cmake

I need to use a new version of SQLite3 in a project built using CMake. To find external dependencies we usually use the FIND_PACKAGE() command which tends to work fine. However, FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3) finds the very old version shipped with the OS rather than the up-to-date version provided by Homebrew. Homebrew refuses to relink to its own headers, binaries and libraries. I guess I could do that manually, but I am hesitant if Homebrew so strongly discourages it (refuses even when --force flag is given).

Any pointers on how to control where CMake looks for SQLite3 would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question because I had the same. Eventually I solved it by telling cmake where to find the Homebrew includes and library:

```
cmake -DSQLite3_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include -DSQLite3_LIBRARIES=/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib ..
```

I hope this helps anyone else wondering how to do it.